# How do I dispose of the sewer liquid in the flask?

Tags: lure-of-the-temptress

I'm currently playing [*Lure of the Temptress*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lure_of_the_Temptress) and I encountered a rather big problem:

I filled the flask that Nellie gave me with the 'liquid' that comes from the sewer. No-one wants to drink it and I have absolutely no idea how to dispose of the disgusting contents.

Is there any way to empty the flask or do I have to start over (I only have one save-game)?